# Are HTTP methods case sensitive?

Tags: http, http-method

To ask a question related to [Are HTTP headers case-sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5258977/are-http-headers-case-sensitive), if HTTP methods are case sensitive, what do most servers do with a "get" or "post" vs a "GET" or "POST"?

For example, it looks like Apache httpd returns "501 Method Not Implemented" in response to lowercase methods, which is what I would expect.

Comment: Methods are indeed case-sensitive (https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec5.html#sec5.1.1)

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth rfc2616 is obsolete, https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7230#section-3.1.1 is the current text -- the point you made stands: methods are case-sensitive.

Comment: Is this question body answerable as written? It seems to request the behavior of "most servers" for conditions that are provably out of spec. Furthermore, the bounty requests an official reference for this undefined behavior, which seems to be either self-contradictory or a list of all major server implementations (and their chosen failure modes) to approximate the question's "most servers".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTTP method names: upper or lower case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27423615/http-method-names-upper-or-lower-case)

Answer (score 4):

> The method token indicates the request method to be performed on the target
> resource. The request method is **case-sensitive**.

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.1.1

> The method token is **case-sensitive** because it might be used as a gateway to
> object-based systems with case-sensitive method names.

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.1

What is interesting, is that while both references say the case is important,
neither one says *what case* should be used. Continuing from the second
reference:

> By convention, standardized methods are defined in **all-uppercase** US-ASCII
> letters.

So now here it does say uppercase, but it also says *by convention*. So on paper,
it would seem that you could also use all lower. In practice, it seems only upper
is accepted:

```
PS C:\> curl.exe -X POST https://www.ietf.org
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <meta name="robots" content="NONE,NOARCHIVE">
  <title>403 Forbidden</title>
```

```
PS C:\> curl.exe -X post https://www.ietf.org
<html>
<head><title>400 Bad Request</title></head>
```

Comment: *Case-sensitive* just means that you have to use the name as specified, without changing the case. The method names are specified as `POST`, `GET`, and so on, so there's no ambiguity here.