# Problem with PATCH method and CORS preflight request

Tags: php, symfony, ionic-framework, cors

I have a problem with the application I’m developing.
The API is in PHP Symfony 4 and the application is made with Ionic 4.

I have a problem when doing PATCH requests. The request works very well on POSTMAN, as well as on my phone
but I have problems with CORS when trying on browser (Google Chrome, Firefox).

I have inquired and I have understood that a PATCH request first goes through a pre-flight request and therefore sends a request
with the OPTIONS method to my API.

I managed this method and returned a code 200 then I allowed the correct headers in my index.php file as follows:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, HEAD, PATCH, OPTIONS, POST, PUT");
```

At the beginning, I had a first error which indicated that the request did not return code 200, so I managed the OPTIONS method in my API.
Then I have the following error:

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

This is strange because the error there did not appear before, and all the other requests work.

In addition, I tried with POSTMAN and the OPTIONS method returns the correct headers.

Can you help me?

Sorry about the rough English.

Comment: do you add the header on the actual request as well? and as far as i know, you don't have to support all http methods.

Comment: On which query should I add headers ? In the front ?

Comment: the cors-headers should be added on all requests, that are allowed cross-domain. not just head or option.

Comment: Yes I added them to the index.php file at the root of my Symfony project

Comment: is the requested resource (you should see which resource is accessed) a static file by any chance (located in the public/web folder or sub folder)? because those are usually delivered directly, without being forwarded by index.php (but you could force such a thing ...)

Comment: Should I put the headers in each method in my controller instead of the index.php file ?

Comment: index.php *should* work, but adding it in the controller might be a good alternative.

Comment: They’ve been in the index.php since the beginning but it doesn’t work

Comment: well in that case, build the response headers manually like `$response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');` (and similar for the remaining headers). of course some response object has to be created. the responses created from symfony might override all headers, possibly ... I wouldn't have expected it though.

Answer (score 8):

For anyone who finds this in this future, I've reproduced these exact symptoms, and solved my issue. The short answer is that when the method is specified on the client-side (e.g. in the `fetch` options), `PATCH` specifically is case-sensitive while other methods are not. It needs to be capitalized.

The explanation, to the best I've been able to deduce, is that even though the [RFC7230](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7230) states that methods should be uppercase, they are also case-sensitive. The browsers smooth over this by automatically capitalizing several of them, I believe based on [RFC7231](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7231#section-4) which defines many of the common methods, but does not define PATCH. Consider the following request initiated from the client side.

```
fetch('https://stackoverflow.com', 
  { method: 'post', 
    body: JSON.stringify({message: 'testing a cors issue'}), 
    headers:  {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
  }
)
```

The normal behavior for at least a Chromium browser is to automatically capitalize the method in the `Access-Control-Request-Method` header of the CORS preflight, regardless of the capitalization my JavaScript uses in the fetch call.

[image: Preflight request with capitalized post method]

Likewise, if the method is `DELETE`, the browser will also automatically capitalize it in the preflight.

However, I found that the `PATCH` method (defined later in [RFC5789](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5789)) is treated like a custom HTTP method, in that it is not forcibly capitalized. It is therefore case-sensitive, which is observable during CORS preflights. If the client app specifies it in lowercase `patch`, that's how it appears in the Access-Control-Request-Method header, and if it's capitalized `PATCH` it appears capitalized in the header.

[image: Preflight showing lowercase patch method]

When you select the `PATCH` method within Postman, it's always capitalized, which masks the root cause of the issue. Even though the error message is in regard to the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header, the root cause that I've seen is the method's case-sensitivity.

Comment: Right, per the HTTP spec — and all other RFCs too — *all* HTTP methods are case-sensitive. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/27427356/441757. So, per the HTTP and other RFCs, `patch` and PATCH are different methods — and `get` vs GET, etc., are also different methods. And so to strictly conform to HTTP/RFC requirements, both HTTP servers and HTTP clients must not treat a `patch` method as if it really meant PATCH, or treat a `get`, etc., method as if it meant GET, etc. So that’s what most HTTP servers actually do. But what HTTP clients do in practice is a different story.

Comment: Browsers actually violate the HTTP spec requirements on method case-insensitivity. See https://github.com/whatwg/fetch/issues/50#issuecomment-188241506. But they violate it in a standard way, defined at https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-method-normalize, which says, *“To normalize a method, if it is a byte-case-insensitive match for DELETE, GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, POST, or PUT, byte-uppercase it.”* So since PATCH isn’t in that list, browsers *never* uppercase `patch`— nor any other method except those in that list. The only reason browsers do it for the listed ones is backward compatibility.

Comment: Issues like these make for a bad day... so apparently "get" and "GET", "post" and "POST", etc. are the same - but (!) "patch" and "PATCH" are not?! Whoever implemented this (in both Safari and Chrome): shame on you! We do need more bashing at bad engineering.

Comment: Really weird behavior. I struggled whit it for a while and my problem was exactly this in google chroome. I'm agree that this is a shame.

Answer (score 0):

```
Environement info-
   ionic (Ionic CLI)             : 4.0.0 
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.0.0
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.8.6
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 0.8.6
   @angular/cli                  : 6.2.6
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 1.1.0
```

For fixing **CORS** error you should follow this steps:

1. **Create** into your Ionic project (in the root)a file call it:
   `proxy.conf.json`
   **write this**(copy/paste) inside:

> ```
> "/api/*": {  
>     "target": "http://myremoteserver/api",  
>     "secure": false,  
>     "logLevel": "debug"  
> }
> ```

2. Open your `angular.json` file and set the line `proxyConfig":
   "proxy.conf.json"` as you can see below into ***"serve"***:

   ```
   "serve": {
             "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
             "options": {
               "browserTarget": "app:build",
               proxyConfig": "proxy.conf.json"
             },
             "configurations": {
               "production": {
                 "browserTarget": "app:build:production"
   ```
3. Open your `package.json` and add this line into the ***script***
   array :

   ```
   "start": "ng serve --port 8100 --proxy-config proxy.conf.json"
   ```

   you shold get something like this (see below) :

   ```
   "scripts": {
       "ng": "ng",
       "start": "ng serve --port 8100 --proxy-config proxy.conf.json",
       "build": "ng build",
       "test": "ng test",
       "lint": "ng lint",
       "e2e": "ng e2e"
     }
   ```
4. After in your command line run this command : `npm run start`

If you followed this steps it's should be **OK**

> For my part it's working !!!

Best regards